# Variant array to Range, set range data type to match accordingly?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, types

When using a variant array in Excel, it will automatically set each value to the appropriate data type like string, doubles, dates, etc.

When I move the entire array to a sheet, the sheets data types wont change with it. If the data is a Date, it will display serials if the range is set as a Text/General. If set to Date, any doubles will look like ####.

I also have some formulas in my array, so setting the range to a Text will cause the formulas to not calculate.

I'm wondering, when pasting the array, is there a way to also set each cells data type to match the data type stored the array?

The output of the array is used to copy and paste into another application, so having the proper format show on the excel would reduce manual work to adjust them afterwards.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `VarType` function [returns a value associated with a data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/vartype-function). The `.NumberFormat` property of a range can be used to set the display format correspondingly. This takes a string so it can be a little tricky to enter correctly. The best way to determine this is to set the cell to the format you actually want and then switch to custom format (in the standard format cells right click menu). The text you see in the bar is what you want in the code.

Comment: Thanks, i'll see what I can do with this and come back to check mark.